# Clear Specific Cache with APC and Magento

Tags: magento, apc

We're using Magento with APC Cache. Using magento's refresh cache doesn't clear the APC cache. We're able to clear the APC cache using our own php script but when we do, we lose everything. We'd like to be able to clear/refresh specific caches so, for instance, we don't lose all of our full page cache when we need to refresh the xml cache. Does anybody know a way to do this?

**current script to flush cache:**

```
<?php
apc_clear_cache() . "\n";
apc_clear_cache('user') . "\n";
apc_clear_cache('opcode') . "\n";
?>
```

**local.xml**

```
 <config>
    ...
    <global>
        ...
        <cache>
            <prefix><![CDATA[MAGE_cache_]]></prefix>
            <backend><![CDATA[apc]]></backend>
        </cache>

        <full_page_cache>
            <prefix><![CDATA[MAGE_fpc_]]></prefix>
            <backend><![CDATA[apc]]></backend>
        </full_page_cache>
        ...
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```